# Global variables in python not working properly?

Tags: python

So i know i shouldn't use global variables like this but if i were to declare a var as global, How would i access it from another function. This doesnt seem to work for me. Note that i am using python 3.6

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request


def f1():                                     
   url = "some url"
   source_code = requests.get(url)
   plain_text = source_code.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
   for td in soup.find_all('td'):
      global tlist
      tlist = list(td)
      print(tlist)


def cleaned():
   global tlist
   print(global tlist)
```

Comment: I think you need to define tlist in the main code as well. Then use global to access it globally within your functions

Comment: `print(global tlist)` is a syntax error. `global` is a statement.

Comment: To expand on what Daniel said, function arguments need to be expressions, and statements in Python are _not_ expressions.

Comment: BTW, please do not bury `global` statements deep in the body of a function, put them up the top of the function body where they logically belong. A `global` statement affects the lookup of that global name through the whole function, not just in statements that occur after the `global` statement itself. But a `global` statement buried in the function implies that it only affects the code below it, so it's misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print (global tlist)` is a syntax error; you can make it work by having the `global` statement on a separate line.

```
>>> def f1():
...     global x
...     x = 1
... 

>>> def f2():
...     print(global x)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print(global x)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> def f2():
...     global x
...     print(x)
... 
>>> f1()
>>> f2()
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setattr:

```
x = XClass()
setattr( x, 'my_attr_name', 'value' )
print x.my_attr_name
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an syntax error during defining cleaned method. It should work, please check;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request


def f1():                                     
   url = "some url"
   source_code = requests.get(url)
   plain_text = source_code.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
   for td in soup.find_all('td'):
      global tlist
      tlist = list(td)
      print(tlist)


def cleaned():
   global tlist
   print(tlist)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i needed. Appreciate the help.